# SQL Date Diff Counts with large list of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm attempting to run a count on a record set based upon dates, but I've hit a brick wall trying to pull this together.

With the below Table1 as an example, I want to take the earliest date and then take the next date that is not within seven days of this date, and repeat. From Table1 below this would effectively give 4 'first dates', 04/01, 12/01, 27/01 and 07/02. Essentially creating a table of 'FirstDate' records to join further tables against

The aim is to have this view for records within 7 days, 30 days, 60 days and 90 days of the 'first date'. (A 30 day count would return 2 'FirstDate' records, 04/01/2018 and 07/02/2018)

I start with a table of Date and ID and finish with Date ID and MinDate.

```
Table 1
    Date         ID      MinDate
    04/01/2018  12345   04/01/2018
    05/01/2018  12345   NULL
    10/01/2018  12345   NULL
    12/01/2018  12345   12/01/2018
    14/01/2018  12345   NULL
    15/01/2018  12345   NULL
    18/01/2018  12345   NULL
    27/01/2018  12345   27/01/2018
    28/01/2018  12345   NULL
    31/01/2018  12345   NULL
    01/02/2018  12345   NULL
    02/02/2018  12345   NULL
    07/02/2018  12345   07/02/2018
    08/02/2018  12345   NULL
    09/02/2018  12345   NULL
```

Greatly appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: What we really need is table definition, sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I've edited the original post as think I over complicated what I was asking by discussing my end goal. Basically I need a table of 'first date' before I can consider anything further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive CTE. The anchor is the minimum date of your table, and the recursion joins with all records with an parametrized amount of days of difference. Finally group by the recursion level (recursive CTEs don't allow aggregates) and find the minimum dates.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Dates

CREATE TABLE #Dates (
    YourDate DATE,
    GroupID INT)

INSERT INTO #Dates (
    YourDate,
    GroupID)
VALUES
    ('2018/01/04', 1),
    ('2018/01/05', 2),
    ('2018/01/10', 1),
    ('2018/01/12', 2),
    ('2018/01/14', 1),
    ('2018/01/15', 2),
    ('2018/01/18', 1),
    ('2018/01/27', 2),
    ('2018/01/28', 1),
    ('2018/01/31', 2),
    ('2018/02/01', 1),
    ('2018/02/02', 2),
    ('2018/02/07', 1),
    ('2018/02/08', 2),
    ('2018/02/09', 1)

DECLARE @MinimumDayDifference INT = 7

;WITH RecursiveDaysDifferences AS 
(
    SELECT
        GroupID = D.GroupID,
        SelectedDate = MIN(D.YourDate),
        Level = 0
    FROM
        #Dates AS D
    GROUP BY
        D.GroupID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        GroupID = C.GroupID,
        SelectedDate = D.YourDate,
        Level = C.Level + 1
    FROM
        RecursiveDaysDifferences AS C
        INNER JOIN #Dates AS D ON 
            C.GroupID = D.GroupID AND
            D.YourDate >= DATEADD(DAY, @MinimumDayDifference, C.SelectedDate)
)
SELECT
    GroupID = C.GroupID,
    SelectedDate = MIN(C.SelectedDate)
FROM
    RecursiveDaysDifferences AS C
GROUP BY
    C.GroupID,
    C.Level
ORDER BY
    C.GroupID,
    C.Level
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 2000)
```

Results for day difference 7:

```
GroupID SelectedDate
1   2018-01-04
1   2018-01-14
1   2018-01-28
1   2018-02-07
2   2018-01-05
2   2018-01-12
2   2018-01-27
2   2018-02-08
```

Results for day difference 30:

```
GroupID SelectedDate
1   2018-01-04
1   2018-02-07
2   2018-01-05
2   2018-02-08
```

If you have thousand of dates, the recursion joins will escalate to a very high number of rows (even if we just display a few of them at the end). You might want to tune up a little the join logic in that case.

Comment: This looks almost exactly what I need thank you. How would I group the recursive count by ID? Thanks again

Comment: @Cam2319 if you need different grouping levels, just group by (and join) accordingly inside the recursive CTE. I edited the query and results to show you an example.

Comment: this is perfect. I will end up running this on a few hundred thousand rows to be honest so I will look to see what I can do with the join logic but think I'll need to accept that this wont run quickly. Thanks again

Comment: @Cam2319 If you join by the Group ID then it won't be so harsh, as the set you will be joining into will be limited by the Group ID. Having an index by GroupID and Date will make the query go very fast. Glad the query helped :)